# Как в Visual Studio посмотреть используемость того или иного свойства класса или метода?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Если класс разработан нами, то мы видим над методам и свойствами CodeLens и можем посмотреть места в программе, где они используются.

А можно ли так же сделать с теми классами, исходных код которых недоступен?

Comment: А разве "Find All References" не выполняет то что вы хотите?

Comment: Object Browser разве не то, что вам нужно? - Ctrl-Alt-J